# How can I force Laravel to use another encryption system other than mcrypt?

Tags: laravel, openssl, mcrypt

I'm updating the my server PHP version from 5.6 to 7.2, and now I can no longer use mcrypt. I'm completely lost as how should I try, but I already tried to changing the cipher from `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` to `AES-256-CBC` in the file `config/app.php`, with no avail. So, how can I change it? I have laravel 5.0.

Comment: are you getting any error

Comment: Why not just install mcrypt?

Comment: I believe you need to go all the way to Laravel 5.5 if you want to move to PHP 7.2